# Installing and running a gem in bash script

Tags: bash, rubygems

I am writing a bash script in mac OSX. now i want to set up librarian-chef,

```
echo "installing the librarian-chef gem"
gem install librarian-chef

echo "librarian-chef installing cookbooks from the recipies"
librarian-chef install
```

and then run it. so that the rest of the bash script can complete but i keep getting this `line 31: librarian-chef: command not found`

so i figured the gem installed fine but the path wasn't refreshed so it couldn't be used? so i tried

```
echo "librarian-chef installing cookbooks from the recipies"
source ~/.bash_profile
librarian-chef install
```

so that it would refresh it but that didnt work?

```
./vagrant_prepare.sh: line 30: ~/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

how can i install it and then use it anyone seen this?

i do have bash profile btw

```
 ls -a
.           .bash_history       .dropbox        .rbenv      .viminfo        Dumps           Pictures        temp
..          .bash_profile       .gem            .redis          Desktop         Library         Public          test.sh
.CFUserTextEncoding .bundler        .gitconfig      .ruby-version       Documents       Movies          VirtualBox VMs
.DS_Store       .cache          .local          .ssh            Downloads       Music           Work
.Trash          .config         .pow            .vagrant.d      Dropbox         Nexus           chronosphere.sh
```

Comment: line 30 is `source ~/.bash_profile`. if i run `gem install librarian-chef` and then run `source ~/.bash_profile` it runs fine. its so strange

Comment: Which path is `librarian-chef` installed? Was that path already in your `$PATH`? Did the `gem install ...` change your `~/.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Reopen terminal and run script again.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "installing the librarian-chef gem"
gem install librarian-chef

echo "librarian-chef installing cookbooks from the recipies"
librarian-chef install
```

Comment: Hi Herman, Thanks for the response. i did have the `eval` within the .bash_profile. the issue was that the script needed a new shell before then next step. unfortunately i don't believe this is possible.